# styling media queries, Ignoring/ overriding parent styles

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, stylesheet

So I'm currently working on a *responsive site* and i'm trying to set the styles in the **media query**. However, the styling in the parent css is conflicting.

**The parent style sheet holds this:**

```
.sec1 p  {

text-align: left;
width: 55%;
margin-left: 8%;
float:left;
margin-top: 100px;
}
```

**And the code for the 768 width:**

```
    .sec1 p  {
    letter-spacing:normal;
    word-spacing:normal;
    font-size: 1.1em;
   width:none!important;
   margin-left:none!important;
   margin-top:none!important;
   text-align:inherit!important;
      }
```

As you can see, i tried to set a width:none; margin-left: none; 
But I don't even know if that's proper or effective,

In short, as you can see by my blaring code what I don't want, ***how do I do this?***

Hopefully I am being clear, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Width `none` is not valid.

Set `width: auto` to revert the item to the default behavior

or `width:0` to set it to 0-width.

Also, for `!important` you need a space between the end of the property value and `important`, like this:

```
margin-left: 0 !important;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, Ive never used the !important tag before but I saw it when I was looking for answers. I noticed I had a float style, and needed to set that to none, because when i set my width to ANYTHING, it would mis align hard, and added to the mess. I don't understand the necessity for your prior comment, but thanks for the reminder?